# Join tables then sum on distinct values

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

I'm working through some Adventureworks Challenges, and I'm trying to whittle down/summarize a joined table.

The following correctly joins my two tables and produces 3 columns:

```
use AdventureWorks2012
select datename(dw,orderdate ) as "Day", LineTotal,OrderQty
from sales.SalesOrderDetail join sales.SalesOrderHeader
on (SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID=SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID)
```

Adjusting it slightly, results in a table that shows only the distinct dates of Monday, tuesday, wednesday, etc...

```
use AdventureWorks2012
select distinct(datename(dw,orderdate)) as "Day"
from sales.SalesOrderDetail join sales.SalesOrderHeader
on (SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID=SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID)
```

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to produce the sum of LineTotal and the sum of OrderQty per day, but not having success.

The closest I've gotten is the following:

```
use AdventureWorks2012
select distinct(datename(dw,orderdate)) as "Day", sum(LineTotal), SUM(OrderQty)
from sales.SalesOrderDetail join sales.SalesOrderHeader
on (SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID=SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID)
group by OrderDate
```

However, this produces many, many rows, instead of just 7 rows and the accompanying totals of LineTotal, OrderQty.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use AdventureWorks2012
select 
    datename(dw,orderdate ) as "Day", 
    SumLineTotal=SUM(LineTotal),
    SumOrderQty=SUM(OrderQty)
from 
    sales.SalesOrderDetail 
    INNER  join sales.SalesOrderHeader on (SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID=SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID)
group by 
    datename(dw,orderdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have adventure works but pretty sure you could do something like this. Notice I am using aliases here to make this a little easier. Also, using datepart and the long hand date part instead of short hand. The short hand version is difficult to remember.

```
select OrderDay = datepart(dayofweek, soh.OrderDate) 
    , sum(sod.LineTotal)
    , SUM(sod.OrderQty)
from sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
join sales.SalesOrderHeader soh on sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
group by datepart(dayofweek, soh.OrderDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use AdventureWorks2012
select datename(dw,orderdate) as "Day", sum(LineTotal), SUM(OrderQty)
from sales.SalesOrderDetail join sales.SalesOrderHeader
on SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID=SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID
group by datename(dw,orderdate)
```

When used, it is the `group by` clause that controls the formation of rows, not the `select` clause. So use the datename function on the orderdate column in the `group by` clause.

Also, please note that `distinct` **is not** a function. so parentheses after the word distinct mean nothing, in fact they are ignored.

Do NOT use `select distinct` when using `group by`, it is redundant.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on using Distinct, I'll keep that in mind going forward.